# Reading in an integer array, and stopping when a string is entered

Tags: c#, arrays, string, integer

```
int [] arr = new int [100];
int count = 0;
int val;
arr[count] = 0;

while(count < arr.Length && (int.TryParse(arr[count], out val)))
{
    arr[count] = Convert.ToInt32.Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I want the user to enter values for an array, and when they enter 'exit' the while loop breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read input first using [`do..while`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-do-statement) loop and use exit condition to get out of while loop if user enters `exit`

```
do
{
   string input = Console.ReadLine();  //Read input from user
   if(input == "exit")  //exit condition
     break;
   if(int.TryParse(input, out int intData))
       arr[count++] = intData;
}while(count < arr.Length);
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with the exit condition

Comment: can you explain what is trouble means here? Any exception? any syntax error? Have you tried my solution.

Comment: Ive switched it to a do while. I get the these two errors.

Convert.ToInt32(bool)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context - on the assignment of the array in the loop

and

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.ReadOnlySpan<char> - on the Try.Parse

Comment: Nevermind, I got it

Comment: I still did not understand why you are getting these errors. If you need any further help, kindly share more code or entire error in the question

Comment: I got rid the error, thank you for the help